# terraform install on MAC Mojvae not working

Tags: macos, terraform

I tried to install terraform running following commands from my terminal on MAC with Mojave OS

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.11/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip

unzip -o terraform_btd/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip
```

Post unzip, I see the terraform binary executable generated.Now, when from the same directory terraform init command is invoked, it throws error:

> -bash: terraform: command not found

I understand some suggestions would be to set PATH variable, but invoking terraform init from the same path where the terraform executable is present should run by default.

This used to work on my previous Mac OS version not sure what has changed here. Is it because of Mac OS version or something else?

Comment: i'd install terraform using homebrew.

Comment: What command are you running? Just `terraform`? Or `./terraform`? If something isn't on your path you need to preface it with `./` if you're referring to something in your directory. In reality though you should unzip it on to your path or use brew to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it is just wrong image I was trying to download, instead of mac zip I was trying to download linux one.

Thanks for all the inputs guys